# $E_1\oplus E_2\neq\mathbb{R}^3$? Once it is 4 dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

For each of the following pairs $E_1,E_2$ of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, determine $E_1+E_2$ and prove if $E_1\oplus E_2=\mathbb{R}^3$:

$E_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x=0 \:\:\text{and}\:\: y=0\};E_2=\{(a,2a,3a):a\in\mathbb{R}^3\}$

$E_1\bigcap E_2=0$, once $z=3a$ and $a=0$. However the basis for $E_2$ can be $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$, which proves $E_2$ has dimension 3.But the $E_1$ has dimension 1, since it can be generated by $(0,0,1)$.

Therefore $E_1\oplus E_2\neq\mathbb{R}^3$

Questions:

Is $E_1\oplus E_2\neq\mathbb{R}^3$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $E_2$ doesn't have the basis $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$. It's true that any point in $E_2$ may be written as a linear combination of those three, but that's only a side effect of $E_2\subseteq \Bbb R^3$. Most importantly, none of your proposed basis vectors are in $E_2$. You can't have a basis of vectors that aren't even inside the space they're supposed to span.

Comment: You are wrong on the Basis of $E_2$. (1,0,0) is not of the requested form! Thus find a correct basis of $E_2$ and it helps you correct the dimensions.

Comment: Hint: A basis for $E_2$ is $(1,2,3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $E_2$ is not three dimensional. It's actually only one dimensional which is easy to see since any two vectors are liniarly dependent since they are of the form $a(1,2,3)$.

Also we can see that $E_1$ is also one dimensional since $x=y=0$, that is the vectors are on the form $z(0,0,1)$.

The sum of two vector space have a dimension not exceeding the sum of the dimensions so $E_1\oplus E_2\ne \mathbb R^3$, but not for the reason you gave.

Comment: Depending on the definition of $\oplus$, it might give a space whose dimension is _exactly_ the sum of the dimensions of the two smaller spaces. I would personally use $+$ for the construction that cares about the fact that they are both subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ (and thus might give a slightly smaller dimension), and $\oplus$ for the construction that just looks at the two spaces independently of whether they are embedded in anything larger.

Comment: @Arthur I think I'm inclined to agree with your recommendation on symbol use here. Personally I'd use the symbol $+$ denoting the set of elements that is the sum of one element from each (which assumes that they are subsets of the same group). I think it's implied that this is what the OP meant since he included the fact that $E_1\cap E_2=0$ as an argument for $\dim (E_1+E_2)=4$